# PHP function clarification

Tags: php, regex, function

I am a beginner so probably this will be an easy answer.
I have this function:

```
function str_space_uppercase($string){
    $tmp_string = $string;
    preg_replace('/(?<! )(?<!^)(?<![A-Z])[A-Z]/', ' $0' , $tmp_string);
    return $tmp_string;
}
```

When I use it (ex: `str_space_uppercase('ExampleSTring');`) the function is correctly called but the value it returns isn't changed (`returns:'ExampleSTring'`).

Now obviously if I use:

```
echo preg_replace('/(?<! )(?<!^)(?<![A-Z])[A-Z]/', ' $0' , 'ExampleSTring');
```

It echoes the correct spaced string.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you calling the function? $text = str_space_uppercase('ExampleSTring');

Comment: preg_replace __returns__ the modified value

Comment: `$tmp_string = preg_replace(...)`? [Preg_Replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) :: the manuals help

Comment: Also, it wouldn't be a bad idea to simplify the regex to `/(?<!^|[ A-Z])[A-Z]/`.

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer (I would propose accepting the one that was posted first with the right solution ;-)), so one of the helpers gets the rep, he/she deserves :)

Comment: @Vince its not about who answers first, its about which answer is BEST. Plus, give time for better answers, community votes and the OP to get to accepting...

Comment: @UnholyRanger Since all answers offer basicly the same solution, I don't see much room for an objective categorization into "better" and "worse" answers here. Though of course in general you are completely right ;)

Answer (score 2):

From the [PHP manual](http://php.net/preg_replace):

> If matches are found, the new subject will be **returned**, otherwise subject will be returned unchanged or NULL if an error occurred.

You aren't storing the result of the `preg_replace()` statement in your `$tmp_string` variable. You should store it, like so:

```
$tmp_string = preg_replace('/(?<! )(?<!^)(?<![A-Z])[A-Z]/', ' $0' , $tmp_string);
```

It isn't actually necessary to use a temporary variable though.

This should be enough:

```
function str_space_uppercase($string){
    return preg_replace('/(?<! )(?<!^)(?<![A-Z])[A-Z]/', ' $0' , $string);
}
```

[**Demo!**](http://codepad.org/C9Apze87)

Answer (score 2):

You need to return the value of preg_replace either on the return statement or into a variable ie:

```
return preg_replace('/(?<! )(?<!^)(?<![A-Z])[A-Z]/', ' $0' , $tmp_string);
```

or

```
$tmp_string = preg_replace('/(?<! )(?<!^)(?<![A-Z])[A-Z]/', ' $0' , $tmp_string);
return $tmp_string;
```

take a look at the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Answer (score 1):

`preg_replace` returns a string and doesn't modify the input string. Change the third line in the function to

```
$tmp_string = preg_replace('/(?<! )(?<!^)(?<![A-Z])[A-Z]/', ' $0' , $tmp_string);
```

et voilà!

Comment: Or, just `return` immediately. While we are at it, ditch `$tmp_string` because it serves no purpose as well.

Comment: Woah, embarassing for me. I did think it did change the imput string, ty.

Comment: Of course using: return preg_replace('/(?<! )(?<!^)(?<![A-Z])[A-Z]/', ' $0' , $string); like Jon said works too. This function can be utilized to put a space between uppercase characters but not the first one and not if the previously uppercase character has already been 'spaced'.

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign the value returned by the preg_replace function to a variable:

```
$tmp_string = preg_replace('/(?<! )(?<!^)(?<![A-Z])[A-Z]/', ' $0' , $tmp_string);
```